# Template function where template argument type depends on function arguments

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

I'm porting some C code to C++, and I came across a macro that has the following the signature.
`bound_check(v, l, h)`

In practice, `l` and `h` are (integer) constants, which lends itself to template functions. However, due to the lenient type safety in C (and general badness of  macros), `v`, `l`, `h` often don't have the same type.

I would like to ensure that `h` and `l` are the same type (say `T`), and `T` to be at least timplicitly convertible to `decltype(v)`.
I could have had `template <typename T, T l, T h> void bound_check(...)`, but that required manually coding the type of `v`. I made an (arguably more dangerous) assumption that all possible type `T`s are signed, and used `template <long long l, long long h>` to avoid hardcoding type of `v`.

I wonder if there's a way that I can call the function as in `bound_check<l, h>(v)`, or in another sense, if there is some trick to do `template <T l, T h> bound_check(T& v)` where type are deduced from arguments before explicit template arguments are parsed, as the title says.

Comment: I see no reason why a simple template function with just one type parameter, and `bound_check` taking all three values, is any worse than trying to make the last two of the three values additional template parameters, instead. don't see what the value-added would be, here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I would prefer to move all compile-time constants to templates. Really a sanity thing, but no real value-added in terms of performance or anything.

Comment: `consteval` in C++20 will make this much easier, without needing to use templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to ensure that h and l are the same type (say T),

It's simple: you can impose they are of the same template type `T`, so if you call the function with values of different types, you get a compilation error because there is ambiguity deducing `T`.

So

```
template <typename U, typename T>
void bound_check (U v, T l, T h)
 { /* ... */ }
```

> I would like to ensure that h and l are the same type (say T), and T to be at least timplicitly convertible to decltype(v).

You can check it with a `static_assert()` (see Nikos C. answer) or you can also SFINAE activate/deactivate the function (by example, in a C++11 way) as follows

```
template <typename U, typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, U>::value>::type bound_check (U & v, T l, T h)
 { /* do something with v, l and h */ }
```

> I made an (arguably more dangerous) assumption that all possible type Ts are signed

Using SFINAE, you can add the corresponding test

```
template <typename U, typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, U>::value
                     && std::is_signed<T>::value>::type bound_check (U & v, T l, T h)
 { /* do something with v, l and h */ }
```

Maybe you can also check that `T` is an integral type (`std::is_integral`): `std::is_signed` is true also for floating point types.

> if there is some trick to do template  bound_check(T& v) where type are deduced from arguments before explicit template arguments are parsed, as the title says.

No, as far I know.

Anyway, if possible, this way you loose the "I would like to ensure that h and l are the same type" check.

> If wonder if there's a way that I can call the function as in `bound_check<l, h>(v)`

Starting from C++17, you can use `auto` for non-type template parameter.

So, before C++17 I suppose the answer is "no".

Starting from C++17, you could write something as

```
template <auto l, auto h, typename U>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(l), decltype(h)>
              && std::is_convertible_v<decltype(l), U>
              && std::is_integral_v<decltype(l)>
              && std::is_signed_v<decltype(l)>> bound_check (U & v)
 { /* do something with v, l and h */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want to pass template parameters. You can just do:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename V, typename LH>
void bounds_check(V& v, LH l, LH h)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<LH>, "'l' and 'h' must be integrals");
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<LH, V>,
        "'l' and 'h' must be implicitly convertible to 'v'");

    // ...
}
```

Also, it looks like `v` is an out-parameter. Since you were prepared to refactor all calls to this function anyway, you might want to make it a return value instead.

Answer (score 0):

In C++17, you might do

```
template <auto l, auto h>
void bound_check(decltype(l)& v)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(l), decltype(h)>::value, "!");
    /*...*/
}
```

and then call it

```
int v /* = ..*/;
bound_check<0, 10>(v);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5dbe6d187682990d)

`static_assert` can be changed to SFINAE, but in current case, I don't think it is adapted.

Future "concept" might probably provide other alternatives.